# ./osmconvert planet-latest.osm.pbf -o=planet-latest.osm.o5m Write error

Tags: linux, openstreetmap

when trying to change the extenxion of the planet-latest.osm.pbf to o5m using OSMCONVERT I get osmconvert Error: write error.

Comment: Is the error shown immediately or after some time? Does the resulting file planet-latest.osm.o5m exist? If so, is it empty or does it contain something? Can your filesystem handle the resulting file size?

Comment: it appeared after a while and the  planet-latest.osm.o5m existed partially completed. I think it is a memory problem.

Comment: Might also be a filesystem problem if it can't handle the file size. The resulting file will be larger than the initial file because it is no longer compressed. What filesystem are you using? Please try to provide more information.

Comment: I got it, I used a smaller file a fewer countries in the .pdf and it worked.

Comment: I also got the same issue , its file is 68GB what I can do , I have run the wget cmd on aws ec2 instance

Comment: The issue is fixed, actually, my ec2 instance has 8GB storage and my file is too big so the storage is full that's why its unable to download the data